# How to batch delete buckets

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

How do I delete buckets in a batch?

Here's what i've tried.

```
def deleteAllBuckets():
    batch = storage_client.batch()
    with batch:
        for bucket in storage_client.list_buckets():
            bucket.delete()
```

Technically it works because the buckets get deleted, however i'm not convinced i'm sending a single batch request. It looks like i'm sending one request per bucket.

Compare the above code to a batch request in Google Cloud Datastore

```
def deleteAllEntities():
    query = datastore_client.query(kind="Charge")
    queryIter = query.fetch()

    batch = datastore_client.batch()
    with batch:
        for entity in queryIter:
            batch.delete(entity.key)
```

You can see that i'm calling a delete method on the batch object. With the storage code, i'm calling delete on the bucket object. Unfortunately the cloud storage python API doesn't have any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the context manager, it automatically adds the request to the batch and it gets executed when exiting the context manager.

However, the problem I see with your code is that you're calling list buckets inside the batch context manager. I think you want to create the bucket iterator outside. Something like this:

```
def deleteAllBuckets():
    buckets_iterator = storage_client.list_buckets()
    batch = storage_client.batch()
    with batch:
        for bucket in buckets_iterator:
            bucket.delete()
```